# Why am I getting the wrong results from my algorithm implementations?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an assignment to make to make Java code methods from the following algorithms (pseudocode):

```
Design Algorithm CalcLowest 
var lowest = first value in the array numList 
For index=1 to count-1 
If value at index is less than lowest 
Set lowest to value at index 
End if
End loop 

Design Algorithm CalcHighest 
var highest = first value in the array numList 
For index=1 to count-1 
If value at index is greater than highest 
Set highest to value at index 
End if 
End loop
```

I have written the following:

```
public int getHighest()
    {   
        int highest = marks[0];

        for (int i=0; i < count +1; i++){

            if(i > highest)

                highest = i;}

        return highest;

        }

 public int getLowest()
    {
           int lowest = marks[0];

           for (int i=0; i < count +1; i++){


               if(i < lowest)

                   lowest = i;}

           return lowest;

           }

    }
```

It runs but the highest value is always 5 and lowest is always 0. Why?

Comment: You are comparing `i` to lowest, you should be comparing `marks[i]` to lowest

Comment: Thanks got it now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing i to lowest

```
if(i < lowest)
```

i will increment for each time you loop. so lowest and highest will always be the same as the amount of times you loop.

Instead of comparing with i, compare with the value at *place number i* in the array.

Comment: If so select it as the answer to your question :)